# Align horizontal image and text links inside ul

Tags: html, css

How do I align the image with the remaining links in the following list?

```
<div id="barra">
    <ul id="botoes">
        <li><a href="/o-meu-perfil"><img src="image.png" width="25" height="25"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Perguntas</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/o-meu-perfil">Pesquisa</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#barra {
    
    position:fixed;
    height:35px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    top:50px;
    background: rgba(250, 0, 250, 0.75);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#botoes li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 10px;
    
}
```

And the image:

[image]

And how to align the whole thing to the left of the bar?
You may check the code at: http://jsfiddle.net/pFBT9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inherent margins from the ul.

```
#botoes {
    margin: 0;
}
```

and remove the line-height:

```
#botoes li {
    line-height: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFBT9/7/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

//html

```
<div id="barra">
    <ul id="botoes">
    <li><a href="#" > <img src="image.png" width="25" height="25">Perguntas</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/o-meu-perfil"><img src="image.png" width="25" height="25">Pesquisa</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
#barra {

position:fixed;
height:35px;
border-bottom: solid 1px;
top:50px;
background: rgba(250, 0, 250, 0.75);
border-radius: 2px;
}

#botoes li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
vertical-align: top;
line-height:5px;
}

#botoes img {
margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a negative margin to the `img`.

```
#botoes img {
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFBT9/4/)

EDIT: [Solid article on negative margins and why it's ok to use them.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

EDIT 2: To the downvoter, could you leave a comment explaining why?

Comment: It worked pretty well. Also for aligning the whole thing to the left. Thanks!